# C# questions for simple program

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am learning user controls in C# so basically I have a class called `Books`. In this class I have a static method `public static string[] GetBooks()`, this method returns the booknames.

```
public static string[] GetBooks()
{
    return myBookList.ToArray();
}
```

Now I have a `UserControl` where I placed a `DataGrid`, and I want to be able to do something like `dataGrid.DataSource = Books.GetBooks();`.

The problem is that the intellisense is not getting the `.GetBooks()` and I think it is because it is static and I want to keep it static. How can I do this and also, where would the best place to make this call? I assume in the behing code file of ascx right?

Comment: Where is myBookList declared?  Is it static also?

Comment: Yes it is private static List<string> myBookList;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that the intellisense is not getting the .GetBooks() and I think it is because it is static and I want to keep it static.

Why?  Does it make sense for this method to be static, i.e., would it be reasonable to assume that all instances of `Books` would share the same underlying Book data?  If not then it shouldn't be static.

If it should be static then you need to reference it like so (as opposed to using an instance reference)

```
var books = Books.GetBooks();
```

I assume you have something like this right now:

```
var b = new Books();
var books = b.GetBooks(); // Won't work, as GetBooks is static, not an instance method
```

Comment: I totally understand, but what if it is insisted to keep it static although it does not make sense?, how can I make a call to it and also should I make a call to it from the .cs of the ascx file?, the Books class is in the App_Code

Comment: *"what if it is insisted to keep it static although it does not make sense?"* I really don't know how to answer that or when that would ever be the case.  Why would it be forced to be static?

Answer (score 1):

If it is static and you're doing it as posted, i.e. Books.GetBooks(), check if the class and the code behind are in the same namespace, or if you're declaring using it. Also be sure the class Books is public. If it is in App_Code, set Build Action = Compile in the Properties.